# How to choose what FOREIGN KEY to create on what attribute?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Assume I have 2 tables with following attributes.

table 1 (customers): id (PRIMARY), customer (UNIQUE), totalspent

table 2 (receipts): id, cost

What indexes do I need to create on customers or receipts to make it so when a customer is deleted from the table all the receipts tied to him via id are deleted as well?

I set receipts.id to primary key, but when deleting entries from customers, they would not be deleted from receipts. Should I make customers.id a foreign key that references receipts.id? Can a primary key be a foreign key?

Comment: Receipts need a customer id column (foreign key).

Comment: So do I mark receipts.customerid as foreign key that references customers.id? I don't need to create any additional indexes on customers.id?

Comment: (`FOREIGN KEY` and `INDEX` are different things.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a cascading foreign key constraint, rather than an index.

```
alter table receipts add constraint fk_receipts_cust
    foreign key (cust) reference customers(id)
        on delete cascade;
```

In MySQL, a foreign key also *happens* to create an index.  This is a "special feature" of MySQL.  The functionality you are looking for is the cascading part.  You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was for!